# Convert a complex JSON file into a simple JSON file using JQ without getting cartesian product

Tags: json, jq

I want to convert a complex JSON file into a simple JSON file using JQ. However, the query I'm using generates an incorrect output.

My (cut down) JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100,
    "foo": [
      {
        "bar": [
          {"type": "read"},
          {"type": "write"}
        ],
        "users": ["admin_1"],
        "groups": []
      },
      {
        "bar": [
          {"type": "execute"},
          { "type": "read"}
        ],
        "users": [],
        "groups": ["admin_2"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "foo": [
      {
        "bar": [
          {"type": "read"}
        ],
        "users": [
          "admin_3"
        ],
        "groups": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to generate a flatter JSON file and combine the users and groups into one field, similar to this:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "users_groups": [
      "admin_1",
      "admin_2"
    ],
    "bar": ["read"]
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "users_groups": ["admin_1"],
    "bar": ["write"]
  },
  {
    "id": 100,
    "users_groups": ["admin_2"],
    "bar": ["execute"]
  },
   {
    "id": 101,
    "users_groups": ["admin_3"],
    "bar": ["read"]
  }
 ]
```

Everything I try in JQ results in me getting an incorrect output (where admin_1 incorrectly has bar=execute and admin_2 incorrectly has bar=write), similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100,
    "users_groups": [
      "admin_1",
      "admin_2"
    ],
    "bar": ["read", "write", "execute"]
  },
   {
    "id": 101,
    "users_groups": ["admin_3"],
    "bar": ["read"]
  }
 ]
```

I have tried many vairiats of this query - any idea what I should be doing instead?

```
    cat file.json | jq -r '[.[] | select(has("foo")) |{"id", "users":(.foo[] | .users), "groups":(.foo[] | .groups), "bar":([.foo[].bar[] | .type])} ] '
```

Comment: Please explain in words what grouping you are trying to achieve.  In particular, it is unclear why the expected output has three separate objects with .id equal to 100.

Comment: The end goal is to have a csv report that shows for each policy id the resource i.e. db, path, topic, etc. (which I excluded from the cut down file) and the access type for each group or user. My issue at the moment is that my flattened file contains one record for each policy, resource... but then lumps all of the accesses for the users and/or groups into one. This gives incorrect  permissions. The grouping of users/groups should be correct for each policy id and resource - how this is achieved I'm not too worried about because I've spent so long getting nowhere!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following filter groups by "type" as the question seems to require:

```
map(.id as $id
    | [.foo[]
      | {id: $id, bar: .bar[].type} +
        {"users_groups": (.users + .groups)[]} ]
    | group_by(.bar)
    | map(.[0] + {"users_groups": [.[].users_groups]}) )
```

### Output

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "bar": "execute",
      "users_groups": [
        "admin_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "bar": "read",
      "users_groups": [
        "admin_1",
        "admin_2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "bar": "write",
      "users_groups": [
        "admin_1"
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 101,
      "bar": "read",
      "users_groups": [
        "admin_3"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

### Variations

To achieve the array-of-objects output format, simply tack on `| [.[][]]`;
it would similarly be trivially easy to ensure that `.bar` is array-valued, though that might be pointless given that the grouping is by `.type`.